# Creating an Excel User Defined Function to match synonyms from a list

Tags: vba, excel, match, user-defined-functions

At my job, we have several rental properties that we manage. Each one of these properties may go by different names. For example a property may be called Amber Gateway, Platinum Gateway, The Gateway, etc. We have maybe 500-600 Excel workbooks floating around with different types of information in them & I might be asked to pull information from various ones.

The lack of a consistent naming methodology prevents me from using a standard Index/Match function to look up data. I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but this has been my stab at solving the problem.

I've created a worksheet that has a list of all the property names in Column A. Any associated names are listed to the right on the same row in Column B, Column C, and so on. Just for simplicity, say there are only 5 properties and all my data is in A1:E5. Then say the property I'm interested in is in F1 and the property list I want to "match" it up against is in G1:G5. So my data would look something like this:

```
River          Stream         Creek         Brook          Rivulet
Apple          Fruit          
Rock           Boulder        Stone         Slab
Candy          Dessert        Sweets
Forest         Trees
```

Given the word 'boulder' and the following list:

```
Candy
Fruit
Creek
Slab
Forest
```

my goal is to return the list position of the synonym 'slab' - in this case, 4. 
I think I can use the below array formula in place of the Match function. to accomplish this:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(--(INDEX(A1:E5,SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:E5=F1)*ROW(A1:E5)),)
=G1:G5)*IF(G1:G5<>"",MATCH(G1:G5,G1:G5,0)))}
```

Now this formula is a bit unwieldy and I was hoping to translate it into a UDF to make it easier to work with. I'm unfamiliar with VBA though, and after doing a bit of searching, I realized that VBA logic works quite differently than Excel Formula logic. Specifically, I don't think I can use = to force my lookup grid into TRUE/FALSE values in VBA like I do in the SUMPRODUCT functions. Do I have to learn VBA in order to implement this as a UDF or is there another solution? In practice, my lookup grid (A1:E5) will be in an external workbook.

If my attempt is completely off the mark, I'm open to other solutions. I know the Match formula function supports wildcards, but it wouldn't work in the case of dramatically different names, so I was hoping for something more comprehensive.

This is my first time asking a question on here, so please let me know if this belongs in a different area or there's any matter of etiquette I'm overlooking.

Comment: sounds like you need to use a dictionary object

Comment: or maybe not. your code would have to be something like this.... find "boulder" and make note of row .... take each value from row and use it to search in the list

Comment: Give more examples of what the arguments you'd pass to your UDF and which results you'd expect to get

Comment: @AndreTerra I'd be passing two arguments to the UDF. A single string and a 1D range of unknown length containing both blank values and strings, but no repetitions. The single string will have several associated strings, but these will not be passed to the UDF. 

If the single string or any of its associated strings are in the 1D range, I'd like to return the relative position of the first match. If there are no matches, an error value would be preferred.

Comment: @jsotola I'm having trouble implementing something like that. I think I can Google how to look into another workbook & how to use Find to locate the row, but the part I'm getting stuck on is searching a list. Do you have any suggestions for how to implement that?